# Selenium cannot set preference for browser.link.open_newwindow

Tags: java, selenium

I'm using Selenium to test my website, normally when i do "profile.setPreference("browser.link.open_newwindow", 1)" i got no problem with it. However, when i try to move everything into a function inside a class, as below:

```
private FirefoxProfile _ffp;
private WebDriver _driver;
private UserAgentList _userAgentList;
....
public void initializeProtocol(){
    this._ffp = new FirefoxProfile();
    this._userAgentList = new UserAgentList();
    setUserAgent();
    this._ffp.setPreference("permissions.default.image", 2);
    this._ffp.setPreference("browser.link.open_newwindow", 1);
    this._driver = new FirefoxDriver(_ffp);
}
```

I got this massage when i change the value to 1, (2 works fine):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Preference browser.link.open_newwindow may not be overridden: frozen
>   value=2, requested value=1

I've been trying to figure out whats wrong but seem like i cannot be able to. Please help. Thank you so much,

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with "browser.link.open_newwindow"

Comment: i do not want to pop up the firefox browser for faster test

Answer (score 0):

Some preferences are locked (frozen) and not available for users to change

```
{
  "frozen": {
    "app.update.auto": false,
    "app.update.enabled": false,
    "browser.displayedE10SNotice": 4,
    "browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting": false,
    "browser.EULA.override": true,
    "browser.EULA.3.accepted": true,
    "browser.link.open_external": 2,
    "browser.link.open_newwindow": 2,
    "browser.offline": false,
    "browser.reader.detectedFirstArticle": true,
    "browser.safebrowsing.enabled": false,
    "browser.safebrowsing.malware.enabled": false,
    "browser.search.update": false,
    "browser.selfsupport.url" : "",
    "browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash": false,
    "browser.shell.checkDefaultBrowser": false,
    "browser.tabs.warnOnClose": false,
    "browser.tabs.warnOnOpen": false,
    "datareporting.healthreport.service.enabled": false,
    "datareporting.healthreport.uploadEnabled": false,
    "datareporting.healthreport.service.firstRun": false,
    "datareporting.healthreport.logging.consoleEnabled": false,
    "datareporting.policy.dataSubmissionEnabled": false,
    "datareporting.policy.dataSubmissionPolicyAccepted": false,
    "devtools.errorconsole.enabled": true,
    "dom.disable_open_during_load": false,
    "extensions.autoDisableScopes": 10,
    "extensions.blocklist.enabled": false,
    "extensions.checkCompatibility.nightly": false,
    "extensions.logging.enabled": true,
    "extensions.update.enabled": false,
    "extensions.update.notifyUser": false,
    "javascript.enabled": true,
    "network.manage-offline-status": false,
    "network.http.phishy-userpass-length": 255,
    "offline-apps.allow_by_default": true,
    "prompts.tab_modal.enabled": false,
    "security.fileuri.origin_policy": 3,
    "security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy": false,
    "signon.rememberSignons": false,
    "toolkit.networkmanager.disable": true,
    "toolkit.telemetry.prompted": 2,
    "toolkit.telemetry.enabled": false,
    "toolkit.telemetry.rejected": true,
    "xpinstall.signatures.required": false,
    "xpinstall.whitelist.required": false
  },
  "mutable": {
    "browser.dom.window.dump.enabled": true,
    "browser.laterrun.enabled": false,
    "browser.newtab.url": "about:blank",
    "browser.newtabpage.enabled": false,
    "browser.startup.page": 0,
    "browser.startup.homepage": "about:blank",
    "browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone": "ignore",
    "browser.usedOnWindows10.introURL": "about:blank",
    "dom.max_chrome_script_run_time": 30,
    "dom.max_script_run_time": 30,
    "dom.report_all_js_exceptions": true,
    "javascript.options.showInConsole": true,
    "network.captive-portal-service.enabled": false,
    "security.csp.enable": false,
    "startup.homepage_welcome_url": "about:blank",
    "startup.homepage_welcome_url.additional": "about:blank",
    "webdriver_accept_untrusted_certs": true,
    "webdriver_assume_untrusted_issuer": true
  }
}
```

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/firefox-driver/webdriver.json

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.